# Random List Generation not working

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random, python-3.5

I am working on a game where I need to randomly generate classes for a list. I use a self-made function `randList` to do this. The code for that function looks like this:

```
def randList(options, num): #RANDOMLY SELECTS NUM ITEMS FROM LIST OPTIONS
returnVal = [] #CREATE A LIST THAT IT RETURNS
for i in range(num - 1): #FOR DESIRED NUMBER OF RETURN ITEMS
    val = r.choice(options) #RANDOMLY SELECT ITEM FROM OPTIONS
    returnVal.append(val) #ADD THAT TO RETURNVAL
    options.remove(val) #REMOVE IT FROM OPTIONS.
return returnVal #RETURN GENERATED LIST
```

I am using that to randomly generate monsters and items in a room like so:

```
class roomParent: #ROOM CHARACTER FINDS
    def __init__(self, entities, floor): #INIT WITH ENEMIES IN ROOM, ITEMS ON FLOOR
        self.entities = entities #ENEMIES THERE ARE
        self.floor = floor #ON FLOOR THERE IS
    def generate(self):
        global enemiesBeat
        if enemiesBeat >= 500:
            self.entities = [dragon]
        else:
            self.entities = randList([goblin, dwarf, slime, naga, troll, beholder], 1)
        self.floor = randList([scrap, scrap, scrap, fireJar, ambrosia, sword, spearhead, armor, potion, slimeball], r.randint(0, 3))

room = roomParent([], [])
```

Just so you know, `goblin`, `dwarf`, `slimeball`, etc. are defined earlier in the code. I don't think they have anything to do with the problem. I generate the room later like this:

```
def main():
    room.generate()
    print("Enemies: " + str(room.entities))
main()
```

I want it to print out a list with two random monsters in it from `room.generate()`, but it always prints `Enemies: []`. There are no errors in the code, and after trying to troubleshoot for 10 minutes, I decided to consult he web with no fruits in result of that labor. Thank you in advance for any help you give.

Comment: Why `for i in range(num - 1)` instead of `for i in range(num)`?

Comment: Also why do you pass `entities` and `floor` as parameters to `roomParent`'s constructor? It looks like you just need to initialise them to empty lists within the constructor, since they get assigned to anyway in the `generate` method.

Comment: As @Tagc says you do `range(num - 1)` instead of `range(num)`. In your sample code you're passing `1` as the 2nd parameter for `randList` so your for loop will be `for i in range(1 - 1)` which won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

As Oliver points out, the reason you get always get an empty `entities` array is because `self.entities` is set to `randList([goblin, dwarf, slime, naga, troll, beholder], 1)` within `generate` (I assume the global variable `enemiesBeat` is less than 500 in your tests).

In your `randList` function you have an off-by-one error that I mention in the comments which means that the generated list will contain one fewer items than specified by `num`. As you try to generate a singleton list for `self.entities` (`num` = 1), you'll actually have it assigned to an empty list.

You can correct this issue by changing `for i in range(num - 1)` to `for i in range(num)` in your `randList` function.

---

As an aside, I don't think you need to pass `entities` and `floor` as parameters to the `roomParent` constructor, since it doesn't seem to have any effect. Instead, you could modify the class definition:

```
class roomParent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.entities = []
        self.floor = []
    ...
```

And instantiate it like this:

```
room = roomParent()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [the random.sample library function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Also, you might want to rethink your capitalization...snake_case is preferred over inCaps for function names.